# Class Cast Exception in Kotlin Quarkus GraalVM Native Image

Tags: kotlin, apache-poi, quarkus, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

**SOLVED:** @geoand mentioned the io.quarkiverse.poi:quarkus-poi extension in the comments, which solved all my problems! See: https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-poi
and: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkiverse.poi/quarkus-poi/2.0.2

I’m trying to create a microservices that responds with an excel file. If I run quarkusDev everything works fine. But after building the native image, I’m getting this error:

```
    2023-07-06 15:54:30,451 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (executor-thread-1) HTTP    Request to /api/excel failed, error id: 0694d603-5557-4806-bd87-3cd93c6730d9-2:   java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlComplexContentImpl cannot be cast   to org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.readFrom(ThemesTable.java:119)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.<init>(ThemesTable.java:87)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:61)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:661)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:165)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:260)
        at   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:118)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.create(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:98)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.create(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:36)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.lambda$create$2(WorkbookFactory.java:224)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.wp(WorkbookFactory.java:329)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:224)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:185)
        at com.test.services.ExcelService.createExcel(ExcelService.kt:13)
        at com.test.services.ExcelService_ClientProxy.createExcel(Unknown Source)
        at com.test.services.ExcelFileService.submitDTO(ExcelFileService.kt:39)
        at com.test.services.ExcelFileService_ClientProxy.submitDTO(Unknown Source)
        at com.test.resources.ExcelFileResource.DTO(ExcelFileResource.kt:79)
        at com.test.resources.ExcelFileResource_Subclass.DTO$$superforward(Unknown Source)
        at com.test.resources.ExcelFileResource_Subclass$$function$$2.apply(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:73)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:62)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.runtime.interceptor.AbstractMethodValidationInterceptor.validateMethodInvocation(AbstractMethodValidationInterceptor.java:71)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.runtime.jaxrs.ResteasyReactiveEndPointValidationInterceptor.validateMethodInvocation(ResteasyReactiveEndPointValidationInterceptor.java:21)
        at   io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.runtime.jaxrs.ResteasyReactiveEndPointValidationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:42)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:30)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:27)
        at com.test.resources.ExcelFileResource_Subclass.DTO(Unknown Source)
        at com.test.resources.ExcelFileResource$quarkusrestinvoker$DTO_d3f979f0d6dd3140a96a1564a9bba43107110fd0.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.Q`your text`uarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:141)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:145)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:775)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:203)
```

This is the function for the xlsx creation:

```kotlin
        fun createExcel(_: List<Input>): ByteArrayOutputStream {
            val inputStream = this::class.java.classLoader.getResourceAsStream("excel-templates/test.xlsx")
            val workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream)
    
            val sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0)
            val row = sheet.getRow(0)
            val cell = row.createCell(1)
            cell.setCellValue("new entry")
    
            val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            workbook.write(baos)
            baos.close()
    
            return baos
        }
```

These are the dependencies:

```kotlin
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-kotlin")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-arc")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-openapi")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-validator")
    //POI
    implementation("org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.3")
    implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.3")
    implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-full:5.2.3")
    //Log4j
    implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.20.0")
    implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.20.0")
```

Using:
Quarkus v3.1.2.Final
Build with:
`./gradlew clean build -Dquarkus.package.type=native -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true`
Image:
quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-mandrel-builder-image:22.3-java17

I’ve also tried to build the "problematic" dependencies at build time (as a additional build arg in the application.properites) but with no effect

Comment: Have you tried adding the Apache POI Quarkus extension?

Comment: Holy shit, **that's it**. Thank you so much for this! I searched for days but never came across this extension.

Comment: Grald to hear it worked. I have added an answer which it would be great if you accept in order to help furure readers to know it's the proper solution without having to read through the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely need to add the [Apache POI extension](https://quarkus.io/extensions/io.quarkiverse.poi/quarkus-poi) which does a few things in order to make POI work on native mode.